# Cannot read file / Operation not permitted 2.79

Tags: interface, blend-files

[image]I can't open files from Blender 2.79. It says:
cannot read file  /  operation not permitted
when i click to select files in dropdown, it doesn’t open.
I can edit / select objects in my files but I can’t select textures to apply, access files

Blender has been asking as of very recently if i wanted to let blender access my desktop where my blender files are located. I went along and accepted so far, but today I didn’t accept and cancel because I wanted to figure out what it was asking me this since it never did before (maybe because I have the cloud storing them?). This is when the issue occurred of not being able to open files from the blender application, saving the same file (or else it saves with @), can’t select any files, textures.

So I am able to open them from selecting the file in finder and opening by finding the blender application. But once the file is opened in Blender, then again it doesn’t let me access files in the dropdown list, select textures. It saved the file with a @. So I try to worked with that file saved with @, but I have the same issues.

I download blender 2.79b but I have the same issue.
I use Macbook 11.6.7

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have the permissions on the files changed at all? It sounds like Blender thinks you don't have read write access on these files anymore. It might be related to you storing them on the cloud. Also I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "it saves with an @" can you post screenshots of that so we can see what you mean?

Comment: I found a thread on the subject:  https://developer.blender.org/T94696. But I  haven't seen any solution. It's related to the folder permission dialog to access my desktop (very recent, I never had these permission dialogs before). Just out of curiosity, I didn't allow access. The desktop folder is the only folder I don't have access to. I have removed all blender files and applications and uploaded both 2.79b and 3.0 and the same issue happens for both. I have no access to my desktop folders where sits all my blender files. I have Macbook Big Sur 11.6.7. Thank you for your help

Comment: Solution: preferences>security&privacy—>privacy> on the left tab, files and folders> find the app on the right tab and check the folder.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution! You can post answers to your own question and mark it as solved, that way it removes it from the unanswered questions queue and other people can use this info down the line if they have the same question.